# Why is longLongValue returning the incorrect value

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSDictionary that contains a key with a value of 4937446359977427944.  I try and get the value of it as a long long and get 4937446359977427968 back?

```
NSLog(@"value1 = %@", [dict objectForKey"MyKey"]); // prints 4937446359977427944 

long long lv = [dict objectForKey:@"MyKey"] longLongValue];

NSLog(@"value2 = %lld", lv); // prints 4937446359977427968
```

Doing:

```
NSLog(@"%lld", [@"4937446359977427944" longLongValue]); // prints 4937446359977427944
```

I'm assuming it is some kind of round off issue since the lower bits seems to be cleared, I just don't know how to stop it (or why it's happening).

The dictionary is being created using `NSJSONSerialization` and the JSON object does (correctly) contain a `"MyKey": 4937446359977427944` entry and the `dict` object is correct.

The value being held in the `NSDictionary` is a `NSDecimalNumber`

Is something being convert to a float behind the scenes?

Comment: You most likely want to switch off to another JSON parser...

Comment: I don't think it's the JSON parser since the dict that is returned dumps correctly using NSLog().  Meaning: It shows the correct value of  4937446359977427944.

Comment: Can this be isolated to a test-case *without* JSON or an NSDictionary? e.g. constructing the actual type/value in the results from objectForKey ..

Comment: Are the values actually different? Or is this an artifact of logging? That is, compare the actual values in the debugger rather than rely on NSLog...

Comment: Yes, they are the same in the debugger as the NSLog() output.

Comment: I can't isolate it without JSON due to JSON producing a NSDecimalNumber object and that is where the issue must be creeping in. NSDecimalNumber must be stored as a double or something like that (although the debug output being correct is perplexing)  I've "solved" the issue by scrapping JSON.  Already spent too much time on this.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDecimalValue` is not stored as a `double`, it's a 64 bits unsigned integer mantissa, an 8 bit signed integer exponent of base 10, and a sign bit.

The problem is that an exact value of an `NSDecimalValue` is only representable as ... an `NSDecimalValue`.

You can get an approximate 64 bits IEE754 value with method `doubleValue`.

When you try to use `longLongValue` you effectively get the result of casting to a long long int the approximate IEE754 value.

You may or may not consider it a bug in the implementation of `NSDecimalValue` (and eventually file a radar and ask Apple to use a different conversion routine). But strictly speaking this is not a bug: it's a design decision.

You should think of `NSDecimalValue` as a sort of *floating point* decimal. In fact it's very similar to a software implementation of what IEEE754 would call an *extended precision floating point decimal number*, except that it does not conform to that definition (because it does not have an exponent supporting at least values between −6143 and +6144 and because it does not support NANs and infinites).

In other words, it's not an extended implementation of an integer, it's an extended (but lacking NANs and infinites) implementation of a double. The fact that Apple natively only provides an approximate conversion to `double` (implying that the conversion to long long int may or may not be exact for any value that exceed 53 bits of precision) is not a bug.

You may or may not want to implement a different conversion yourself (with a category).

Another possible point of view is to consider the problem being a bug in the JSon implementation you used. But this is also highly debatable: it gave you a `NSDecimalValue` and that's arguably a correct representation. Either you operate with the `NSDecimalValue` or **you** are responsible for any conversion of it.

Comment: I would consider it as bug of `NSDecimalNumber`, because that class is documented to represent decimal integers up to 38 digits correctly. I would assume that `longLongValue` returns a correct result as long as there is no overflow. But for a decimal number `d`, `[d longLongValue]` seems to return the same value as `(long long) [d doubleValue]`, and that is of course imprecise as soon as more that 53 bits are used.

Comment: To you last point: I would also expect that I can read a integer number from JSON data into a "long long" as long as there is no overflow. That the NSJSONSerialization uses `NSDecimalNumber` (a subclass of `NSNumber`) should be an implementation detail that I don't want to care about.

Comment: The class is documented to have 38 digits of mantissa, no to represent 38 digits of decimal integers. And even if it was documented to represent 38 digits of decimal integers it's not documented to guarantee conversion to `long long int`, the only non-inherited accessor is in fact doubleValue.

Comment: JSon is not defined to give you `long long int` either. It gives you an integer. On a platform that supports different types that can contain an integer, a JSon parser could give you any of them and the parser is arguably correct even if the various numeric types do not natively support conversion to each other.

Comment: Conversion from `NSDecimalInteger` to `long long int` does not exist (except through a `double`). This is not a bug, it's a design decision. At most it may be considered the lack of desirable feature, which is not the same as a bug.

Comment: NSDecimalNumber is not stored as a double, but it always responds that it's a double if queried with objCType.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your are interested in a simple solution or just looking into the details of why the loss of precision takes place.

If you are interested in a simple answer: `-[NSDecimalNumber description]` products a string with the value, and `-[NSString longLongValue]` converts a string into a `long long`

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4937446359977427944"];
long long longLongNumber = [[decimalNumber description] longLongValue];
NSLog(@"decimalNumber %@ -- longLongNumber %lld", decimalNumber, longLongNumber);
```

outputs

```
2014-04-16 08:51:21.221 APP_NAME[30458:60b] decimalNumber 4937446359977427944 -- longLongNumber 4937446359977427944
```

Final Note

`[decimalNumber descriptionWithLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]` may be more reliable is your app supports multiple locales.

Comment: That's a perfect timing I would say :).

Comment: Maybe you can just use `number.stringValue.longLongValue` to get the long long value, and it won't be localized.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in quick solution to the problem, as per Analog File proper answer:

```
long long someNumber = 8204064638523577098;
NSLog(@"some number lld:               %lld", someNumber);
NSNumber *snNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:someNumber];
NSLog(@"some number NSNumber:          %@", snNSNumber);
NSString *someJson = @"{\"someValue\":8204064638523577098}";
NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization
 JSONObjectWithData:[someJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
 options:0
 error:nil];
NSLog(@"Dict: %@", dict);
NSLog(@"Some digit out of dict:        %@", [dict objectForKey:@"someValue"]);
NSLog(@"Some digit out of dict as lld: %lld", [[dict objectForKey:@"someValue"] longLongValue]);
long long someNumberParsed;
sscanf([[[dict objectForKey:@"someValue"] stringValue] UTF8String], "%lld", &someNumberParsed);
NSLog(@"Properly parsed lld:           %lld", someNumberParsed);
```

Results in:

> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.997 Tutorial4[97950:303] some number lld:
>   8204064638523577098
>
> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.998 Tutorial4[97950:303] some number NSNumber:
>   8204064638523577098
>
> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.998 Tutorial4[97950:303] Dict: { someValue =
>   8204064638523577098; }
>
> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.998 Tutorial4[97950:303] Some digit out of dict:
>   8204064638523577098
>
> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.999 Tutorial4[97950:303] Some digit out of dict as
>   lld: 8204064638523577344
>
> 2014-04-16 14:22:02.999 Tutorial4[97950:303] Properly parsed lld:
>   8204064638523577098