# NSNumber longLongValue returns 0 erroneously

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber, floating-point-conversion

I've got an `NSNumber` whose value looks like this in the debugger:

> (lldb) po avg
>
> 377.57142857142857142857142857142857142

When I ask it for its `intValue`, I get 377. Fine. But if I ask it for its `longLongValue` I get 0.

What gives?

**Update:** The full scenario is that I've got an array of NSNumber objects, and I'm getting its average like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myNums = nil; //assume this is full of numbers
NSNumber *avg = [myNums valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
int64_t result = avg.longLongValue; //this gets 0
```

I've stopped here in the debugger and I can `p [avg longLongValue]` and get 0.  `p [avg intValue]` gets 377.

**Update 2:** Here is a reliable reproduction:

```
NSArray *testArr = @[@(392), @(392), @(339), @(394), @(393), @(394), @(339)];
NSNumber *testAvg = [testArr valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];
int64_t testRes = testAvg.longLongValue;
NSLog(@"Result is %lli", testRes);
int res2 = testAvg.intValue;
NSLog(@"Int result is %i", res2);
```

The result log is:

> Result is 0
>
> Int result is 377

Comment: Try using `long long` instead of `int64_t`. And show how you know it is zero.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't think the assigned type matters. I can call `longLongValue` in the debugger and get 0 back.

Comment: Are you using p or po? Use the p command.

Comment: @rmaddy I've tried both. `po` gives `<nil>`. `p` gives 0.

Comment: Try logging the value. Sometimes the debugger is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70749/discussion-between-mr-jefferson-and-rmaddy).

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @robmayoff 6.1.1 (6A2008a)

Comment: What is the debugger output of `po [avg class]`?

Comment: @robmayoff `po [avg class]` gives `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: `NSNumber *num = @(377.57142857142857142857142857142857142) ;`, intValue and longLongValue are all 377.

Comment: @KudoCC - I think this is some oddity of floating-point to integer conversion. If it helps, try making an array and doing the average call.  My array contents are `392, 392, 339, 394, 393, 394, 339`

Comment: Weird, I get 377 on both intValue and longLongValue. `NSArray *myNums = @[@392, @392, @339, @394, @393, @394, @339] ;
    num = [myNums valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.self"];`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Same Xcode version, on Mac OS X 10.9.5. Here's my test case: https://gist.github.com/mayoff/e2c5be3e2262fbac8c03

Comment: @robmayoff see update with repro steps.  I tried it in a different project to make sure it wasn't environmental too.  I'm on Yosemite 10.10.2.

Comment: I am on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and I can't reproduce the problem too.

Comment: Show the printed output.  Also extract and print the `doubleValue`.

Comment: I'm guessing that when you get zero `testAvg` is nil for some reason.

Comment: I will post more stuff tomorrow morning. But I know testAvg is not nil. I can get at it from the debugger just fine.

Comment: Well, it's axiomatic that you're not showing us the real code.

Comment: @HotLicks - If I copy the code from my Update 2 in the question and paste it into a new Xcode project and run it, I get 0 from `longLongValue`. Simple as that.  I've tried it in current Xcode (6.1.1), 6.2 Beta 5, and 6.3 Beta 1.

Comment: You still don't show us a copy of your NSLogs of the various values, taken from a single run.

Comment: What about the categories you have in place?

Comment: @HotLicks - no categories. Like I said, I can create a new project in Xcode, paste that code, run it, and get that output. OS X 10.10.1, current Xcode release and current betas.

Answer (score -2):

Your `po [testAvg class]` gives `NSDecimalNumber` which is the problem.

These links would explain why:

[Link 1](http://bharath2020.in/2013/09/30/longlongvalue-in-nsdecimalnumber/)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418224/why-is-longlongvalue-returning-the-incorrect-value/12421451#12421451)

As link 1 suggested you should do `[[testAvg stringValue] longLongVale]`

Comment: Those links explain how an NSDecimalNumber (of a sufficiently large value) cannot be accurately represented as a `double`, but they do nothing to explain now an NSDecimalNumber might translate to zero as a `long long`.